# comparing multiple proportions over time

Tags: time-series, proportion, count-data, contingency-tables

I have a dataset of 22 fish species in a fish market, sampled monthly, from 2007 to 2011. I want to see if there is a statistically significant change in their relative proportions over time. I first thought of a contingency table (by aggregating the monthly data into yearly totals), but the 22x5 cell array seems too big!

Comment: Do you have 5 time points? Where does the "5" come from? If you have monthly data for 5 years, that should be 60 time points. Are you aggregating the months into yearly totals? As for the proportions, are the total number of fish in the market at any one time fixed, or can you have the same number of a given fish, but increasing numbers of another?

Comment: @gung Hi-yes, I aggregated the results by year, resulting in 5 yearly totals. There is variation in the overall numbers of fish and individual numbers within each species coming into the market.

Comment: 22x5 isn't too big necessarily, but you shouldn't use a contingency table here. Time series methods will probably be appropriate b/c the data will be autocorrelated. Also, you should probably fit the different fish individually (perhaps w/ a VAR) rather than as proportions, but I'll let someone more expert in those methods address that issue.